# Adding total on top of report

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to make the sum/total of a field at the top of the first page without using sub-report?

I would like something like this:

```
Total: 300

Employee | Salary
Emp1     |  100
Emp2     |  200
```

Comment: Check out the duplicate you will find an answer with a complete example, if you do not want the total in columnHeader but in pageHeader or title band (only first page), just move the textFields to the appropriate band, if you still have problem let me know

Comment: Thank you @PetterFriberg

Comment: I everything is solved consider to accept the duplicate, otherwise let me know if you still need a answer (what the problem remains)